# Kafka mirror maker not replicating topic

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-mirrormaker

I've two Kafka clusters running within docker container on two different ec2 instance while I'm running mirror maker my topics are getting replicated

source cluster: 10.0.0.2
destinations cluster: 10.0.0.1

producer.config

```
bootstrap.servers=10.0.0.2:9092
# specify the compression codec for all data generated: none, gzip, snappy, lz4
compression.type=none
acks=1
batch.size=100
client.id=mirror_maker_producer
retries=2147483647
max.in.flight.requests.per.connection=1
```

consumer.config

```
bootstrap.servers=10.0.0.1:9092

# consumer group id
#group.id=test-consumer-group
exclude.internal.topics=true
client.id=mirror_maker_consumer
group.id=mirror-maker
auto.offset.reset=earliest
partition.assignment.strategy=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RoundRobinAssignor
```

I am running following command of destination cluster

```
bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.MirrorMaker --consumer.config config/consumer.properties --producer.config config/producer.properties --num.streams 3 --whitelist mirror_8
```

topic exists on source cluster but its not replicating on destination cluster

Comment: do you have automated topic creation set on the target cluster?

Comment: yes, its set to true.

Comment: could it be a problem that you have `bootstrap.servers` set to `10.0.0.2` although (according to your text) that is your source cluster?

Comment: I'm not sure, I'm using IP instead of broker id can that be an issue ?. I've tried running same command on source cluster the topic gets replicated on destination cluster but data doesn't can you suggest me the right steps ?

Comment: You obviously need to consume from the *source cluster*. There's no way to connect to broker IPs. Using EC2 DNS names would be better, if you have them. By the way, MirrorMaker2 would be a better choice overall